# Fatal error: Class not found in Zend Framework 2 when deployed in server but not locally

Tags: php, zend-framework, deployment, zend-framework2

When I use my application from localhost it works fine, but when I deploy the application in the server I get the next error:

*Fatal error: Class 'PFC\Model\GestoresPFC' not found in /var/www/html/pfpdi/module/PFC/Module.php on line 59*

I'm using a module with the next tree structure

- PFC/

  - Config/
  - src/

    - Controller/
    - Form/
    - Model/

      - gestoresPFC.php
      - gestoresPFCTable.php
      - PFC.php
      - PFCTable.php
  - view/
  - autoload_classmap.php
  - Module.php

Where **gestoresPFC.php** is like:

```
<?php 
 namespace PFC\Model;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

 class GestoresPFC implements InputFilterAwareInterface
 {
     public $gestor_id;
     public $plan_id;
     protected $inputFilter;                       // <-- Add this variable

     public function exchangeArray($data)
     {
         $this->gestor_id  = (isset($data['gestor_id'])) ? $data['gestor_id']     : null;
         $this->plan_id     = (isset($data['plan_id']))     ? $data['plan_id']     : null;

     }

      public function getArrayCopy()
     {
         return get_object_vars($this);
     }

     // Add content to these methods:
     public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
     {
         throw new \Exception("Not used");
     }

    public function getInputFilter()
     {
         if (!$this->inputFilter) {
             $inputFilter = new InputFilter();


             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'gestor_id',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 100,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $inputFilter->add(array(
                 'name'     => 'plan_id',
                 'required' => true,
                 'filters'  => array(
                     array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                     array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                 ),
                 'validators' => array(
                     array(
                         'name'    => 'StringLength',
                         'options' => array(
                             'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                             'min'      => 1,
                             'max'      => 11,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ),
             ));

             $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
         }

         return $this->inputFilter;
     }
 }
```

And **Module.php** is like:

```
<?php
namespace PFC;

 use PFC\Model\PFC;
 use PFC\Model\PFCTable;
 use PFC\Model\GestoresPFC;
 use PFC\Model\GestoresPFCTable;
 use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
 use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;


 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                 __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
             ),
             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                 'namespaces' => array(
                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                 ),
             ),
         );
     }

     public function getConfig()
     {
         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
     }


     public function getServiceConfig()
     {
         return array(
             'factories' => array(
                 'PFC\Model\PFCTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('PFCTableGateway');
                     $table = new PFCTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
                 },
                 'PFCTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new PFC());
                     return new TableGateway('plan_formacion', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                 },
                 'PFC\Model\GestoresPFCTable' =>  function($sm) {
                     $tableGateway = $sm->get('GestoresPFCTableGateway');
                     $table = new GestoresPFCTable($tableGateway);
                     return $table;
                 },
                 'GestoresPFCTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new GestoresPFC());
                     return new TableGateway('gestores', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                 },

             ),
         );
     }

 }
```

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Can you share your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gestoresPFC.php` should be `GestoresPFC.php`. The filename needs to match the class name. I'm guessing you developed this site on a case-insensitive file system (e.g. Windows) where this wouldn't matter.